# angularjs - one time binding not give any performance improvement in `ng-repeat`

Tags: javascript, angularjs, performance

To increase the speed in `ng-repeat` instead of 2 way I have changed to single way binding to imporove the speed. But I am not finding any speed performace here at all. can any one help me to improve the speed in `ng-repeat` please?

my process out put shows as no big changes when i shuffle between 2 with single way `ng-repeats`

```
VM780 script.js:30 Process time: 124 //single way
VM780 script.js:30 Process time: 132 //double way
VM780 script.js:30 Process time: 120 //single way
VM780 script.js:30 Process time: 121 // double way
VM780 script.js:30 Process time: 124 // single way
```

here is the `ng-repeat` i use :

```
<div class="showList"> 
      <ul>
        <li ng-repeat="d in data">{{::d.name}}{{::d.address}}{{::d.city}}{{::d.country}}</li> 
        <!-- <li ng-repeat="d in data">{{d.name}}{{d.address}}{{d.city}}{{d.country}}</li> -->
      </ul>
    </div>
```

[Live Demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/BAtt8oOhC6zvwstBeYv8?p=preview)

Comment: It additionally should be `::d in data`. The optimization is pointless if you don't know what you're optimizing. In this case next digests will be affected after populating `data` - and there are no next digests. And it is not single way binding at all. It's one time binding.

Comment: actually `::d in data` throws error, instead I use `d in ::data` - But still no performance improvements.

Comment: Yes, it should be d in ::data. Of course, there won't be performance improvements on initial digest. And of course there will be performance improvement for `d in ::data` on next button presses - because data will be bound only once. This may not behave expected (changing $scope.data won't update the table), but there are significant performance improvements - like 100ms vs 5ms.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem here are wrong expectations of performance improvements. The script does nothing that would benefit from these optimizations. It generates a new set of data every time.

Similarly, the methodology for testing performance is also wrong, it just measures that time that it takes to generate a new set of data and do initial digest for it - which would be the same every time.

One-time bindings are beneficial during *subsequent* digests over *same* set of data.

A way to measure this is something like

```
  setInterval(function () {
    console.time('digest');
    $scope.$apply();
    console.timeEnd('digest');
  }, 1000)
```

This way

```
<li ng-repeat="d in data">{{::d.name}}{{::d.address}}{{::d.city}}{{::d.country}}</li>
```

will show some performance improvements over

```
<li ng-repeat="d in data">{{d.name}}{{d.address}}{{d.city}}{{d.country}}</li>
```

And it becomes critical when watchers count becomes higher.